# float:center doesn't display well on newsletter for Windows Phone

Tags: css, windows-phone-7, windows-8, html-email

I am working on a newsletter design using Ink as an email template.

If I want to center an image I have to use float:center and margin: 0 auto. It works well on iPhone Mail app, iPhone Gmail app, and Android Gmail app but it doesn't works on the native Windows Phone email.

Does anybody knows a trick to make it work?

Alex

Comment: in my knowledge,there is nothing like `float:center`, instead give `width:xx%` and then add `margin:0 auto` to it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to use `margin: 0 auto` you need to display the element as a block-level element.

This means you should use `display: block;`.

Another option is using `text-align: center;` for the parent element, to align center the inline children horizontally on the page.

### Update:

Here is **[a JSFiddle Demo](http://jsbin.com/abUYeqi/1/edit)** which demonstrate how to do the above logic.

CSS:

```css
img {
  width: auto;
  max-width: 100%;

  margin-top: 10px; /* Just for Demo */
}

.img1 {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.parent {
  text-align: center;
}
```

HTML:

```html
<img class="img1" src="http://placehold.it/100/50">

<div class="parent">
    <img class="img2" src="http://placehold.it/100/50">
</div>
```

Comment: I've used display: block and it doesn't work. Also text-aling: center is not woring for <img src="">

Comment: Here is the line: <img src="logo.png" style="outline: none; text-decoration: none; -ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic; width: auto; max-width: 100%; float: center; clear: both; display: block; margin: 0 auto;" align="center">

Comment: @user2989327 I added a jsfiddle demo to demonstrate the approach in action.